# CodeDeploy Instances are reintializing even after termination

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I was trying how to create a code-deploy instances for my script and then was unable to understand how it works.

Then I went to my dashboard I saw that 6 code-deploy instances are running and was shocked. I tried to **terminate** them but after a while new instances are starting again.

I went to code-deploy window and deleted my code-deploy instance available there but all the 6 instances are still running and I am not able to stop them from re-initializing.

I also saw there is a similar question here but no one has answered it.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: ok, I understand. Will not do this again. Thanks @halfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CodeDeploy application is associated with an autoscaling group with a 'desired' instances count set to 6. AutoScaling groups are a separate and independent resource, and will persist even if you delete all of your CodeDeploy resources.

Find this group and update your 'desired' count to 0, and the instances will scale down.

### Further Reading

- [AWS Documentation - Auto Scaling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html)
- [AWS Documentation - Integrating AWS CodeDeploy with Auto Scaling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/integrations-aws-auto-scaling.html)